# Creating alias or PATH for application

Tags: bash, path, alias

I installed application (on macOS) SAOImageDS9 and it's location is **/Applications/SAOImageDS9.app**

I would like to run this application from anywhere in terminal by typing **ds9**.

I tried to create alias or PATH (not sure what is difference) but nothing works ... probably I am doing something wrong.

After typing in terminal **type ds9** I am getting message **ds9 is aliased to `/Applications/SAOImageDS9'**.
When typing ds9 in terminal message is **-bash: /Applications/SAOImageDS9: No such file or directory**.

Any advice, suggestion would be more than welcome.

Comment: Your alias says `/Applications/SAOImageDS9`, your location is `/Applications/SAOImageDS9.app`.  These must match.

Comment: And after they match I have the sam problem.